# How to remove \n from the middle of texts in a list of texts in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I scraped a webpage for a list of headings that take on the following form in the source code:

```
<h2 class="story-heading"><a href="somelink.html">Crash Highlights
Indonesia’s Poor Air
Safety Record</a><span class="product-label theme-nyt-now "><span class="visually-hidden">NYT Now</span><i class="icon dot-logo-icon"></i></span></h2>
```

I just want the text.

I get the following list:

```
[u'Crash Highlights\nIndonesia\u2019s Poor Air\nSafety RecordNYT Now', u'Palestine Joins\nHague Criminal\nCourt, Risking\nU.S. SanctionsNYT Now', ... ]
```

Every string has the `"\n"` character and ends in `"NYT Now"` How can I remove the NYT Now? It is my understanding that `get_text()` should only retreive the function inside the `<a>` tab

Here is my code:

```
url="<website link>"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

headings_list=[]

for heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading"):
    for text in heading.find_all('a'):
        headings_list.append(heading.get_text().strip())

print headings_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do what you are looking for:

```
heading.get_text().replace('\n',' ').replace('NYT Now', '')
```

Comment: this worked best. thanks! I also added a strip() at the end to remove any leading or ending empty spaces.

Comment: Actually this will change headlines like "NYT Now Will Offer API for Web CrawlersNYT Now" in an unexpected way. Better combine the answers like in `heading.get_text().replace('\n',' ')[0:-7]`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
headings_list.append(heading.get_text().strip()[:-7])
```

to take the heading without the last 7 characters.